# Lisp -- let and eval not working together

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

In clisp, running

> (let ((x 10)) x) ==> 10

but

> (let ((x 10)) (eval 'x)) ==> variable x has no value.

Comment: [`eval`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eval.htm) does not have access to lexical variables. This behaviour is by design.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to do (setq y '(+ 1 x)) and then do something like (subst 10 for x in y)? How would I do that without eval?

Comment: `((lambda (x) (+ 1 x)) 10)` is the expression you want to run. You *can* use `eval` to splice in the `(+ 1 x)` into the lambda, though that's still pretty hacky. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Why does `(progn (defparameter x 'hello) (let ((x 10)) (eval 'x)))` yield `10` then?

Comment: @uselpa defparameter makes `x` name a dynamic variable

Comment: @coredump- I am aware of that. But `eval` then uses the value of the lexical variable, not the dynamic one. See the answer I linked to.

Comment: @uselpa the answer you linked is right: let also modifies the dynamic environment, but if it was a lexical `y`, the lexical binding of `y` would not be visible in eval (if `y` was not quoted, the value would be available, like with any other function)

Comment: @uselpa  **"But eval then uses the value of the lexical variable, not the dynamic one."** no, since defparameter *globally* makes x special, there's no lexical variable x there; let is establishing a new dynamic binding of x.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thanks for the clarification!